# Functional analysis and $\textsf{CH}$

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, soft-question, set-theory

Does anyone know any result in the field of Functional Analysis which holds only if one assume one of the following :

- $\textsf{CH}$
- $\neg \textsf{CH}$
- $\textsf{GCH}$

Comment: I believe there has been some work involving $C^{*}$ algebras and the continuum hypothesis. I even recall a book on the topic, but I don't remember any details at the moment. *(moments later)* Ah, here it is: [**An Introduction to Independence for Analysts**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0521339960) by H. G. Dales and W. H. Woodin (1987).

Comment: And there is this survey: [*Set theory and* $C^*$-*algebras*](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0604198.pdf) by Nik Weaver (2006).

Comment: Also some of the things Ilijas Farah is doing.